# Rails WikiCreole Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, creole

I have an inherited project using the creole gem (0.5.0).

In my view this line seems to break but I can't find out anything about it:

```
<%= WikiCreole.creole_parse(@a.content) %>
```

The error message is `NameError in Knowledgebase_article#view uninitialized constant ActionView::Base::CompiledTemplates::WikiCreole`. If this line  is removed then the page will render fine.

The problem is I can't seem to find out much about the error anywhere so I was hoping that someone on SO would know where to start.

Comment: may I know what is your rails version?

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention that, it's 2.3.14 and ruby version is 1.8.7 so quite old versions.

Comment: Ok let me check it ....

Comment: @Rajarshi it worked, thank you! If you post it as an answer I will mark it as accepted. It was the first one the app was using though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try `<%= Creole.creolize(@a.content)%>`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer as to why my specific setup wasn't working, first of all I hadn't installed the `WikiCreole` gem, so:

```
gem install WikiCreole
```

Then, I was missing the `require` statement from my model:

```
require 'wiki_creole'
```